# Is the public IPv4 address and default gateway for my home router owned by IANA?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

In the web interface for my home wireless router, I can see the following information:

[image]

For the *public IPv4 address*, I see:

https://myip.ms/info/whois/10.206.55.182

And for the *Default Gateway* I see:

https://myip.ms/info/whois/10.206.48.1

both owned by *IANA*. Are those IP addresses some "defaults" for all routers?

They are not the same as my public (outbound) IP address (that I can get with icanhazip.com) or the default gateway/my router IP address (which is only visible locally).

Comment: Out of curiosity: you ask about the address of your ISP-facing interface (10.206.55.182/21) being "owned" by IANA, but somehow you have no problem accepting that the address of your *inward-facing* interface (192.168.0.1/24) is also "owned" by IANA. In fact, both address ranges are defined as *Private Addresses* in the *exact same standard* ([RFC 1918 – *Address Allocation for Private Internets*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918#section-3)). What is the reason that you find it normal to have your own IP registered by IANA but not the ISP's?

Comment: Those (10.0.0.0/8) are a reserved pool of Class-A of private addresses. Your ISP has put you behind a NAT. The same as what your home gateway does mapping all the "home lan" 192.168.0.0/24 onto the (natted 10.206.55.182) address your carrier provides you. INTERNET  -> carrier WAN [10.0.0.0/8] -> home-GW [192.168.0.0/24]-->PC Actually the fact is that the 65k ports available to any public ip are shared between many customers instead of a full range given to every customer. This means you can't publish a service on the public internet without asking your carrier for a port map.

Comment: @DDS they are not class A addresses they are classless address in what used to be the class A range. The RFC1918 "Address Allocation for Private Internets" makes specific reference to RFC1519 "Classless Interdomain Routing" from 3 years earlier. Private networks never used the class system. IT engineers often mistakenly equate "/8" with "Class A"

Comment: PSA: see if your ISP will turn on IPv6 for you. The more people using IPv6, the better, because the sooner the world can rid itself of this awful, awful NAT and CGNAT stuff.

Comment: Can you say how an IP address could be "owned"?

Answer (score 36):

You are looking at some
[Reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses):

> In the Internet addressing architecture, the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) and the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) have reserved various Internet Protocol (IP) addresses for special purposes.

Specifically the range of 10.0.0.0–10.255.255.255 is used for local communications within a private network.

In other words, these IPs are local to some local network and
were allocated by some DHCP server which is not on the public
internet. They are meaningless outside of this network.

One possibility is that your ISP put you on
[Carrier-grade NAT (CGNAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT),
meaning that your ISP is allocating addresses inside its own
network, while for the public internet it uses one IP address
for several of its clients. You may check this by using a website
such as
[whatismyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/),
to see the internet address the ISP is using.

So, yes, they are owned by IANA and were reserved by it
for allocation inside local networks.

Comment: "these IPs are local to your local network" should probably be "these IPs are local to your ISP's local network"

Comment: `10.206.55.182` is the *public IP address of the router* so on the ISP side of the network.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, you're right, I should have gone further. This must be a CGNAT.

Comment: If this is CGNAT, then the ISP ought to be using 100.64.0.0/10 addresses, since they are reserved for this purpose. But it still seems more likely that this is an ISP mis-implementing CGNAT than anything else.

Comment: Actually /10 gives you 2**22 addresses. But yeah I've seen mobile providers assign 10.x range (for CGNAT). And in the past one provider was using an address range that was actually assigned to the UK ministry of defence (the MOD were not actually using it)

Comment: The range `100.64.0.0/10` only gives 4,194,304 addresses, while `10.0.0.0/8` gives 16,777,216, which might be the reason that this was chosen. In effect, the ISP could choose anything it likes, since its local network is invisible to the internet. However, this particular choice seems bad to me, as many routers also allocate IP addresses in the same range for their local network, so this may cause some confusion and is perhaps the reason behind this post.

Comment: "One possibility is that your ISP put you on Carrier-grade NAT (CGNAT)" That is inaccurate. A NAT is a prerequisite for private IP to route packets to and from the internet. A cgNAT is a NAT capable of routing packets for an ISP. Therefore, it is the ONLY possibility.

Answer (score 17):

As harrymc's answer correctly notes, your ISP has probably put you on [Carrier-grade NAT (CGNAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), so your router "public network" is actually connected to the ISP's CGNAT network. This network is not public, so its uses a subset of the [IANA-reserved IP address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) 10.x.x.x, and a second NAT device exposes it as a single public IP address (or maybe a few addresses).

Here's how it works:

```
+------------------------------+
|                              |
| Your private network         |
| 192.168.0.x (192.168.0.0/24) |
|                              |
+---[192.168.0.1  ]------------+
    [Your router  ]
+---[10.206.55.182]----------------+
|                                  |
| ISP's private network            |
| 10.206.(48-55).x (10.206.0.0/21) | <<< calculated from your router's "Public subnet mask" of 255.255.248.0
|                                  |
+---[10.206.48.1       ]-----------+ <<< your router's default gateway. It may technically be some other router inside the ISP CGNAT network
    [ISP's CGNAT router]
+---[some public IP    ]-------+ <<< whatismyipaddress.com will show your this IP
|                              |
| The open Internet            |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```